# Does exists any way to redirect pipe output as file?

Tags: shell, stream, pipe, xmllint

I'm use `xmllint` to select node, and my test purposed `1.xml` is looks like this

```xml
<resources>
   <item>
        <label>LABEL</label>
        <value>VALUE</value>
        <description>DESCRIPTION</description>
   </item>
   <item>
        <label>LABEL</label>
        <value>VALUE</value>
        <description>DESCRIPTION</description>
   </item>
</resources>
```

```sh
$ xmllint --xpath '/resources/item/value' 1.xml
<value>VALUE</value><value>VALUE</value>
```

Command likes above is work well.

And then i try to combine with pipe `|`, error occurred

```sh
$ cat 1.xml | xmllint --xpath '/resources/item/value'
Usage : xmllint [options] XMLfiles ...
...(help info)
```

I suppose the reason is pipe transmit process `cat`'s output as a stream, but `xmllint` can only receive file path as argument. So, does any way to solve this problem? or maybe some alternative?

Of course. If my guess if fault, point at real reason is also pretty helpful to me.

### sorry

My English is poor. Please excuse grammar or typing error. I'm trying my best to improve.

Answer (score 0):

I have never used `xmllint`, but from its [man page](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/unix_commands/xmllint.htm), I can see:

> The xmllint program parses one or more XML files, specified on the command line as XML-FILE (or the standard input if the filename provided is -

Therefore, the following should work:

```
xmllint --xpath '/resources/item/value' 1.xml
```

or, if you **insist** that the input should come via stdin,

```
xmllint --xpath '/resources/item/value' - <1.xml
```

Comment: According to what you say, i had solved my problem just add `-`. Now the command likes `cat 1.xml | xmllint --xpath '/resources/item/description' -`. But i still confuse is what role does the `-` play over there?

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative, you can pass xmllint command to stdin via `--shell` option

```
echo -e 'cat /resources/item/value\nbye' | xmllint --shell 1.xml
```

Or

```
(echo 'cat /resources/item/value'; echo 'bye') | xmllint --shell 1.xml
```

Comment: Good alternative. But seems can only use in limited scene

Comment: It's a very powerful feature. You can take a look at this bash script [xml2xpath](https://github.com/mluis7/xml2xpath), it's used there.